# How to upload .txt document to firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a cloud storage web-app using Reactjs (only for learning). I want to create a text document using an editor that I have built but I want to know how I can upload documents from my online text editor to the backend(Firestore). I have already created the text editor but I don't know how to connect the editor with the back-end so that whenever I click save in my text editor the text file must get stored in my cloud store app (something like google docs saves are uploaded to google drive). It would be great if someone can just tell me some methods so that I can do all this using ReactJS .
link to text editor.
https://text-editor-project.atharvadeshmukh.repl.co
this editor is just a sample.

I need a way to upload the text to a xyz.doc format when i click save in my editor

Comment: check this article? https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-upload-files-to-firebase-cloud-storage-with-react-and-node-js-e87d80aeded1

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ReactJS, I would recommend going through the [getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) guide of firestore and look at web. Point of note is that firestore is meant to store data in Json format rather than plain text. In case your text document is actually structured in any other format if might be worth using firebase storage to store the actual document and use firstore just as a way to store document information (user who created it and any other metadata that is not available by default through firebase storage) and reference to the actual document.
Please have a look at firebase storage [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start) as well

Comment: Yes i have planed something like but even if i want to upload the the files from my text editor how can i  do that. https://text-editor-project.atharvadeshmukh.repl.co if this is the text editor then how to export the text to .doc format and then upload back to firebase storage.

Comment: @AtharvaDeshmukh read the documentation that is mentioned in the answer.
You can easily convert the output contents of your text editor to html and store the whole html in firebase storage. Since your question is about a general approach involving the technologies you want to learn, I have given you some ideas for solution.
There is enough material to actually help you with the steps. Have fun learning.